# methode-missing error in rails when starting a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am new to rails, just going through a tutorial "learn ruby on rails" Have successfully push files/folders to the github repository.

I want to start the server with **rails server** to view the default home page of the rails app on my browser but I keep getting a `NoMethodError`.

I am running the command in my project directory "**\projects\Rails\blog>**",and i have installed all the required gems with the command "**bundle install**" after specifying Gem version as giving in the tutorial.

I have configured Rails to connect to email server ("Gmail") also. The error is as shown in the image below.

```
$ rails new learning    #creates a new rails project
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/learning.git
$ rails generate figaro:install #To create application.yml file to hold  ENVs.
$ git push -u origin master
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "add configuration"
$ git push
$ rails server
```

Comment: add a bit of code the details you posted has nothing to do with rails

Comment: i just found typo in the image which you shared.. "perfom_deliveries" instead of "perform_deliveries", it may causes issue

Comment: thanks @ prakash it was a typo error, am now go to go